# Which Hypervisor should I use?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualization, fedora, xen

This is more of an advisory question.
I am into a virtualization project and need a good software to do that.
Basically I am into Desktop virtualization that allows to run multiple operating systems on the same physical hardware.
I cannot afford to buy the developer APIs of VMWare, so I have moved on to Linux.

I did some research on the same and learnt that Xen can't be installed on Fedora 16. Is it true? because I am doubtful of the same.

My Questions are :

**Which Operating system should I install?** 
Fedora 16 /Ubuntu 11.10 /Any other?

**Which software for the same?**
Xen/Any other?

I want an advise because I am using it for the first time and any post-installation problems will hurt me bad.

I am a newbie in linux... Can anyone please help me out on this?
P.S. : No offence, I am not asking which is the BEST! I am just asking what will suit my purpose.

Comment: Have you considered KVM, since it is a Linux host ... also your question is too unspecific. Should you install **what** as host or guest? ... I guess you mean the host, but it's still guess-work.

Comment: I am sorry for vagueness. Yes I mean host os. And regarding KVM, I was just reading about it in the next window. Have u used it or any other experience that u can share?

Comment: oh yeah, I'm using it on multiple machines, but you'll have to be a bit more specific about the information you need about it :)

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED : I have edited my question to specify the requirements.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for APIs you are probably most interested in libvirt for simple ESX style api for interfacing LOCALLY with the virtualization hypervisor on your system.

libvirt works with qemu, kvm, and xen and probably more.

- http://libvirt.org/

redhat has traditionally had better virtualization support in its enterprise offerings.  but fedora is not that.  I'd suggest ubuntu oneiric.

If you are looking for a REST API to talk to a large number of virtualization servers... ala vsphere.  I'd suggest looking at openstack.

- http://www.openstack.org/
- http://www.devstack.org/
- http://www.trystack.org/

Answer (score 1):

I have used [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) several times. I had some production servers running virtualized on Linux with it. I think it was bought by Oracle, but still open source and free (I hope :) 
Take a look at it, may be is what you need. I remember installation and configuration was easy, and very well documented.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to begin with Linux as a Windows guy. Why not to intall Microsoft Virtual PC? I bet it does support Linux and all modern distributions will likely work.

I also recommend VirtualBox as a good starting point for you if you want to use Windows as a hypervisor.

If you want to use Linux as hypervisor, I recommend to stick with standard KVM. E.g. in RHEL (CentOS) or Fedora you can use it easily. Definitely read this document: **Virtualization Getting Started Guide**

http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/18/html/Virtualization_Getting_Started_Guide/index.html

As it explains everything to start with virutalization including very easy setup and installation on Fedora Linux. It also applies to Ubuntu, but the installation procedure will be different. But you will end up using the very same tools and software.